# How to know if type conversion is safe?

Tags: c++, casting

I have type A and B as template parameters and I want to check if type B can be safely converted to type A. AFAIK int to double conversion is safe but not the reverse. So how to find out if the conversion is safe and there will be no data loss? For now I want to know for the integraltype only.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean safe. `int` to `double` can lose precision.

Comment: I didn't know `int` to `double` can lose precision. Can you shed more light on it?

Comment: Better get a cup of whatever you drink ready and [start reading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It'll take a while.

Comment: _"... Can you shed more light on it?.."_ a 64-bit integer can hold 2^64 different values precisely.  A 64-bit floating point value has only 52-bits for the mantissa, 11-bits for the exponent and 1 sign bit ([IEEE 754 - Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), so it has less bits for holding numbers precisely but a much larger range.

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks for clarification but is there anyway to know if it is lossless?

Comment: _"... to know if it is lossless?..."_ Easiest is to roundtrip the number: int -> double -> int and then compare the first and last values.  I think this should be possible at compile time with `constexpr` will experiment and report back.

Comment: afaik it would be possible at compile time only if the original int is known as compile time.